# Calculating $\sum_{m=0}^\infty x^m \binom{n+m-1}{m}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to calculate the mean and variance of a particular mass function and, in order to do that, I need to calculate the following series $(x<1)$:

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty x^m \binom{n+m-1}{m}$$

I don't know how to solve series like this, any help?  Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$$\binom{n+m-1}{m} = \frac{n(n+1)\cdots (n+m-1)}{m!} = (-1)^m\frac{(-n)(-n-1)\cdots (-n-m+1)}{m!} = (-1)^m\binom{-n}{m}$$

then

$$\sum_{m = 0}^\infty x^m\binom{n+m-1}{m} = \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \binom{-n}{m}(-x)^m = (1 -x)^{-n}$$